# can html server controls give better performence than asp controls in asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, htmlcontrols

Now i am working with a webapplication in asp.net c#. My pages works fine, but it takes more time to load than normal. One of my friend says to try html server controls instead of asp controls. Is it true that html controls works better than asp controls in this situation? Or is it because of some other reasons? I'm using a button click event and there are almost 5 to 8 sql queries works behind it. Lagging in page load happens when i click the button.I am using MySql.

Answer (score 0):

See if you are using ASP.NET, the names tells that you have to user server controls. So no need to implement html controls. Just use only asp.net server controls. If you need better performance during the page load as well as page render,you can have look of MVC3/4.

Comment: I used 3tier architecture and it is almost completed. So i can't change the whole thing.I don't know how to use page_render function. Can anyone explain it? Thank you.

Comment: If its complited then you can't do it again. But if you are looking for faster performance,you always give priority to MVC. You will get more than you are expecting. Rendering the page is the concept included in MVC only.

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase performance, just changing the server side to html controls will not be great impact

1. Check the DB Query time and fine tune if it takes more time
2. Avoid viewstate if it is not necessary control/page level
3. Use server control wherever you do dynamic process & events like
   setting/getting in server side
4. Use Div based layout
5. Move js/css files and minify it
6. Use effective caching mechanism
7. Image Sprite/Font Awesome technique.

   8 .There are many by refactoring the application code and design...